# React-native: margin not taken into account in a flex layout

Tags: react-native, flexbox

I encountered a few times issues with margins when layouting views using flexbox.

I managed to reproduce the issue with a small code snippet:

Here is a custom component:

```
class MyView extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <View style={
        {
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          width: 50,
          height: 50
        }
      }/>
    );
  }
}
```

and here is how I use it:

```
<View style={{ flexDirection: 'column' }}>
  <MyView />
  <MyView style={{ marginTop: 12 }}/>
</View>
```

So I am expecting to see 2 green squares on top of each other, separated by 12px (due to the marginTop). Instead here is what I see:

[image: nomargin]

The two squares touch each other. I have no idea why the margin is not taken into account.

I tried debugging the bottom view with the inspector tool, here is what's getting displayed:

[image: nomargin-debug]

You can actually see the margin on this image (light orange). Any idea why the margin is not taken into account?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
class MyView extends Component {
  render() {
    const { style } = this.props;
    return (
      <View style={
        [style, {
          backgroundColor: 'green',
          width: 50,
          height: 50
        }]
      }/>
    );
  }
}

MyView.propTypes = {
  style: React.propTypes.shape({
    marginTop: React.propTypes.number
  })
}

MyView.defaultProps = {
  style: {
    marginTop: 0
  } 
}
```

You are passing `style` into `MyView` as a `prop`. I've added `propTypes` and `defaultProps` as you only pass the `style` prop on occasion.

From the React docs

> All of the core components accept a prop named style.

Because your component is not a core component, `style` doesn't work as you expect it to.

Comment: That totally makes sense, I did not realise that I was skipping the `style` prop. Is there any reason why we should not always write `style={[style, {...}]}` in custom components?

Comment: The style shape is to have control on what can be changed on the style, from the outside, right?

Comment: Yes that's correct, you're effectively only allowing the `marginTop` style property to be passed through to your Component. Anything else will throw a warning.

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same issue when using flex and I used

> justifyContent = "space-between"

margin top and marginBottom didn't work for me .Later when I removed the justifyContent and just put

> alignItems: "center",
>     flexDirection: "column"

instead margin top and bottom worked for me .